# Can we call the graph of the function $f:\mathbb [-2,3]\rightarrow \mathbb R,\,\,\, f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ "Parabola"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, definition

Let's define the function $f:\mathbb [-2,3]\rightarrow \mathbb R,\,\,\, f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ , can we call the graph of this function "Parabola"?

I would answer my question as follows:

The graph of the function  $f:\mathbb [-2,3]\rightarrow \mathbb R,\,\,\, f(x)=x^2+3x+5$ specifies a Parabola in the range in which it is defined.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: I don't know.  Is the book fussy about a parabola must be complete and include the graph for the entire domain of $(-\infty, \infty)$.  If the book is that fussy than, no, that *part* of a parabola but not a parabola itself.  If the book isn't that fussy than, yes, that graph is parabolic. (All quadratic functions-- 2nd degree polynomials-- with a non zero leading coefficient are parabolic.... by definition.)

Comment: On the one hand, is a circular arc a circle? On the other hand, it is widely agreed that a parabola is obtained when some slice is made of some conic.

Comment: ", it is widely agreed that a parabola is obtained when some slice is made of some conic. "  Is it?  I bring the issue up but it comes down to how fussy the book is.  It's either acceptable to call it a parabola or it is a "parabolic arc".  For the most part though we should assure the PO they are correct that 2nd degree polynomials graph as parabolas.

Comment: Depending on context and audience and your goals, you can call it "Arthur" or "Lord Papshmere the Twelfth". What I'm saying is that this question is not well-defined without further context.